# ERROR [QueryResource] Cannot get excel for query

Tags: export, pentaho, xls, saiku

I executed a query in Saiku and tried to export it to Excel. It throws error page.

Below are the error logs :::

```
10:05:22,885 ERROR [QueryResource] Cannot get excel for query (01976CF4-EB20-DE88-94CA-E8E8F2A74EA5)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPlatformFont(FontManager.java:3409)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment$2.run(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:263)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.<init>(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:164)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<init>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:254)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Please assist in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the system fonts installed on your box, I'm guessing you're running a headless Linux system?